# Unicode symbols in Git for Windows

Tags: windows, git, unicode, cmd

Not entirely sure how to best explain, but would it be possible to use [certain](https://github.com/sindresorhus/figures/blob/master/index.js#L5-L41) Unicode symbols, not supported by the Windows Command Prompt, in Git for Windows? Preferably without using Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

The `git-bash.exe` packaged with [git-for-windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) does support those unicode characters. (it uses [minTTY](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/))

[image: support]

But the `cmd.exe` console <del>does not</del> does (as pointed out by [kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720999/kostix) [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132581/unicode-symbols-in-git-for-windows/34133115?noredirect=1#comment56014153_34133115)) with a Unicode (TrueType) font set, although those ones (✔', '✖', '★') are not included in the TrueType fond like Lucida Consola.

Comment: That's not quite correct: `cmd.exe` *does* support Unicode input (and output -- provided the program attached to the console uses Unicode-aware console API; GfW does since 1.8.x), just to actually make use of it one should have a Unicode (TrueType) font set for the console window, and that font has to contain the glyphs of the relevant script.

Comment: @kostix I agree, and tried Lucida Console, but I suspect it does not include the relevant glyphs.